# How to skip InstallDir Dialog on upgrade

Tags: wix

I would like to supress the InstallDirDlg on upgrade. But my approach doesn't work.

I tried to skip the InstallDirDlg using

```
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back"
         Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">NOT Installed</Publish>
```

I tested it by installing Version 1.0.0.0 and then Version 1.0.1.0 but the InstallDirDialog still shows up.

I'm quite new to WiX so maybe I'm missing something.

Here's the Product.wxs file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="MyApp" Language="1031"
           Version="1.0.1.0" Manufacturer="Abid"
           UpgradeCode="8dc49e86-c23a-4541-bef2-259bdec14a57">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <UI>
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
      <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next"
               Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" 
               Value="WelcomeDlg">NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>
    
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />
    <Property Id="INSTALLDIR">
      <RegistrySearch Id="ProgramRegistry" Type="raw" Root="HKCU"
                      Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' 
                      Name='InstallDir' />
    </Property>

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="Eine neuere Version von [ProductName] ist bereits installiert." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
<!-- ... --->
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `NOT OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED` instead of `NOT Installed`?

```
  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">NOT OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED</Publish>
```

Comment: That didn't work. InstallDirDlg still appears on upgrade.

Comment: Do you face any error or it just goes to InstallDirUpgradeDlg during upgrade after applying this condition?

Comment: No error shows up. After clicking Next in WelcomeDlg, InstallDirDlg is being displayed.

Comment: @Abid I have updated the answer. Use NOT OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED in the WelcomeDlg publish statement. Please try that one and let me know if that solves the issue.

Comment: Didn't work. Upgrade is being installed correctly, but InstallDirDlg still appears on upgrade.

Comment: Weirdy Wx! Sorry @Abid, let me check some other docs and will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

`NOT Installed` won't work since the newer Version, the upgrade itself isn't installed.

If you use the MajorUpgrade element the property

```
WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
```

should evaluate to true on an upgrade, so try using NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED in your condition.

As far as I know `UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` and `PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED` may also sometimes be set on an upgrade, but those aren't necessarily as reliable.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Is there any way to debug the evaluation of a condition like WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED?

Comment: You could use a LaunchCondition that aborts the setup and shows you an error message to evaluate whether it is set or not. Just use an condition element within your product element like this https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/block_install_on_os.html

Comment: Thanks. With the launch condition I noticed that `WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED` is false whereas `Installed` is true.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old post, but I recently ran into the same problem and couldn't find a solution here that really works.

As LeonardDM said I had to use the WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED, yet this alone didn't do the trick.
Just in combination with the Order attribute of Publish it really skipped the InstallDirDlg on Updates:

```
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" 
         Control="Next" 
         Event="NewDialog" 
         Value="InstallDirDlg" 
         Order="5">NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" 
         Control="Next" 
         Event="NewDialog" 
         Value="VerifyReadyDlg" 
         Order="2">WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Publish>
```

Hope this helps anyone still searching.